# Receive UDP messages without allocating new buffer

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, sockets, udp

When trying to use `UdpClient.Receive` I noticed that it just returns a byte array. Does this allocate a new buffer for every packet? As far as I know, allocating a new byte array for every received packet is bad for performance and memory usage. To get around that same problem when using Tcp, I used an ArrayPool to rent the buffers. But how would I do that with Udp?

I thought about using the same method like with Tcp and just using a socket, but udp is not stream based and therefore that approach makes little sense (I don't know how big one packet will be and I cannot continually read from a stream like in Tcp).

TL;DR:

**How do I save performance when receiving UDP packets while still always receiving the full packet?**

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry for asking but what would I use to querry the next packets size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When trying to use `UdpClient.Receive` I noticed that it just returns a byte array. Does this allocate a new buffer for every packet?

Typically, yes.

Internally, `UdpClient` uses a fixed-sized `byte[65536]` array to read each packet.  If a received packet is exactly that size, the internal buffer is returned as-is.  However, if the received packet is less than that size, which is usually the case, then it allocates a new `byte[]` of the actual packet size, copies the internal buffer's data into that new array, and then returns it.

> I don't know how big one packet will be

It is possible in the Winsock API to determine the next packet's actual size without extracting the packet from the socket's queue.  Winsock's `recvfrom()` function has a `MSG_PEEK` flag for that purpose.

`UdpClient.Receive()` does not support that flag, however the `UdpClient`'s underlying `Socket` does in its `ReceiveFrom()` method, eg:

```
byte[] ignore = new byte[0]; // the buffer parameter of ReceivFrom() can't be null!
EndPoint ep;

int size = UdpClient.Client.ReceiveFrom(ignore, SocketFlags.Peek, ref ep);
// obtain a buffer of sufficient size ... 
UdpClient.Client.ReceiveFrom(buffer, size, SocketFlags.None, ref ep);
```

Although `Socket.ReceiveFrom()` does allow a 0-length `byte[]` array (it will pass a NULL pointer and 0 buffer length to Winsock's `recvfrom()`), what I'm not sure about is whether `Socket.ReceiveFrom()` will actually return the next packet size, or if it will throw a `SocketException` if you try to peek into the queue using a `byte[]` array that is smaller than the actual packet (as I am not sure whether or not `recvfrom()` reports a `WSAEMSGSIZE` error when the `MSG_PEEK` flag is used).

To avoid this potential issue, keep reading ...

> How do I save performance when receiving UDP packets while still always receiving the full packet?

Rather then trying to pool arrays, I would suggest you simply use a single 64K `byte[]` array (like `UdpClient` does internally), since UDP packets will never exceed that size.  Simply use `UdpClient.Client.ReceiveFrom()` directly instead of using `UdpClient.Receive()`, eg:

```
byte[] myBuffer = new byte[65536];
EndPoint ep;

...

int received = UdpClient.Client.ReceiveFrom(myBuffer, ref ep);
// use myBuffer up to received bytes ...
// use (IPEndPoint)ep if needed ...

...
```

This way, you can re-use a single `byte[]` array for multiple reads (just as `UdpClient` does internally).